# Migrate all of IIS6 to IIS7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, iis-7, iis-6

Most of the how-tos and tutorials I've found online have shown how to move a single site off of IIS6 to IIS7.  Unfortunately, I have slightly over 100 subdomains in my current IIS6 setup and it will take days to complete this migration using this method.

Can anyone explain to me or give an example of how I would move the entire IIS6 configuration (configuration, inetpub, etc) to an IIS7 server?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [IIS Web Deployment Tool](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy), particularly the [documentation](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7/) on migrating from IIS6 to IIS7.

For migrating all sites, you would change the `-source` parameter to be `-source:webserver60` instead of the metabase path. Then after you move the package, the destination for the import would be `-dest:webserver`.

Here is a link to the [web deploy command line documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568996(WS.10).aspx), it goes over all the different options that allow a migration like this to happen.

Comment: Right, but that only moves the first site in the configuration.  I have multiple sites / subdomains that need moved.  The -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 only transfers one site.  How do I move all of IIS?

Comment: @LinuxGnut: I updated my answer with some additional detail regarding moving an entire web server.

Comment: +1 Just used this tool a few weeks ago to migrate about 60 sites for a client.